# Why isn't this function working?

Tags: php, function, oop

I have declared the beats function and am trying to use it. What is the difference between `var_dump(is_a($sci, 'Scissors'))` and `var_dump($roc->beats($sci))`? When I run this code the first var_dump returns true and the second false. I want both to return true.

```
abstract Class Option
{
    private $beats;

    public function beats($opponentsChoice)
    {
        return is_a($opponentsChoice, $this->beats);
    }

}

Class Rock extends Option
{
    private $beats = 'Scissors';
}

Class Paper extends Option
{
    private $beats = 'Rock';
}

Class Scissors extends Option
{
    private $beats = 'Paper';
}

$roc = new Rock;
$pap = new Paper;
$sci = new Scissors;

var_dump(is_a($sci, 'Scissors'));

var_dump($roc->beats($sci));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `private` variables.

`private` variables are scoped only to the class they are defined in. `Option::$beats` is a different variable than `Rock::$beats`.

If you change your variables to be `protected` instead, that will work, since all members of a class hierarchy will share `protected` variables (and methods).